# Android ErrorPopup above ActionBar in a NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-edittext, popup, nestedscrollview

i'm facing the problem explained by the pictures. In short, when i scroll the NestedScrollView the ErrorPopup comes over my ActionBar. What I want is to hide the errorPopup when it reaches the bottom of action bar... And I don't know how to do that. Already tried setting the elevation of my actionbar. Didn't work.

What I'm using:

Device: Motorola Moto G (XT1068)

System: Android 6.0

Google Libraries: 24.1.0

[image: Error on editText]

[image: The Problem]

Below the code of my XML:

activity_create_account_step2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:theme="@style/myownappTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/MyActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/myownappTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/actionBarTitleText" />

        <View style="@style/view_separator" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_behavior="com.myapp.myownapp.utils.ContainerScrollingBehavior">

        <include layout="@layout/content_create_account_step2" />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_create_account_step2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearBottom"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/textLabel">

                <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.FontEditView
                    android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    style="@style/font_style"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="@string/full_name"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_tiny" />

                <View style="@style/view_separator" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearPosition"
                style="@style/linear_container_style.vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.FontTextView
                    style="@style/font_style.label"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/position" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerPosition"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_icon" />

                <View style="@style/view_separator" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearEnterpriseName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/textLabel">

                <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.FontEditView
                    android:id="@+id/txtEnterpriseName"
                    style="@style/font_style"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="@string/enterprise_name"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_tiny" />

                <View style="@style/view_separator" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearEnterprisePhone"
                style="@style/linear_container_style.vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.FontTextView
                    style="@style/font_style.label"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/commercial_phone" />

                <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.myownappPhoneInput
                    android:id="@+id/txtEnterprisePhone"
                    style="@style/font_style"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearPeoplemyownapp"
                style="@style/linear_container_style.vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.FontTextView
                    style="@style/font_style.label"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/people_will_use_myownapp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerPeoplemyownapp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_icon" />

                <View style="@style/view_separator" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearSegment"
                style="@style/linear_container_style.vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.FontTextView
                    style="@style/font_style.label"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/segment" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerSegment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_icon" />

                <View style="@style/view_separator" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearStaff"
                style="@style/linear_container_style.vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.FontTextView
                    style="@style/font_style.label"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/staff" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerStaff"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_icon" />

                <View style="@style/view_separator" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearChallenge"
                style="@style/linear_container_style.vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.FontTextView
                    style="@style/font_style.label"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/what_is_your_challenge" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerChallenge"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_icon" />

                <View style="@style/view_separator" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTerms"
                style="@style/font_style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="@string/info_userTerms"
                android:textColor="@color/medium_grey" />

            <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/btnTerms"
                style="@style/font_style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/userTerms"
                android:textColor="@color/water" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/list_icon" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View style="@style/view_separator" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.myapp.myownapp.views.widgets.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_positive_action"
                style="@style/font_button_text_style"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_muggie"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/action_start_now"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/water"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```